# Models relation not working when trying to get the children models in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm having a model `Question` that belongs to model `Exam`. `Exam` can have many questions (one-to-many relation). I've no problem with storing the data, but when I try to get the questions for the exam with `Exam::find($exam->id)->questions;` I get `NULL`. I've `dd` the result for `Exam::find($exam->id)` and the relations are empty: `#relations: []`.

This is how I've registered my `Question` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Question extends Model
{

    public $timestamps  = false;
    protected $fillable = ['question', 'correct_answer', 'category_id', 'type'];

    public function questionCategory():belongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(QuestionCategory::class);
    }

    public function exam(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
    }
}
```

And this is the `Exam` model:

```php
namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Exam extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function question(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

Here is the DB schema for the question's table from the migration file:

```
Schema::create('questions', static function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('question');
            $table->integer('correct_answer')->nullable();
            $table->integer('question_category_id')->default(1);
            $table->integer('exam_id');
            $table->string('type')->default('text');
        });
```

Also this is how I'm saving the data for the questions:

```
$request->validate([
    'examId' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'questions' => 'required'
]);

$exam = Exam::find($request->input('examId'));
$questions = $request->input('questions');

foreach ($questions as &$question_entry) {
    // create the question if it doesn't exist
    if ((int)$question_entry['id'] === 0) {
        $question = new Question();
    } else {
        $question = Question::find($question_entry['id']);
    }

    $question->exam_id = $exam->id;
    $question->question = $question_entry['body'];
    $question->type = $question_entry['type'];
    $question->question_category_id = $question_entry['category'];
    $question->save();     
}
```

The saving to the DB is successful and I can see the entries in the DB. And if I try to do something like `Question::where('exam_id',1)->get()` I will get the questions from that exam, but I don't understand why when I try to get the results from the parent model (like `Exam::find(1)->questions) I get` NULL`. It seems like there is no relation between the two models.

I'm using Laravel 10 with Homestead and Breeze.

Comment: You can name the relation as you want, so your error is just a typo. A hint on the nature of the error would be that you received `NULL` instead of an empty collection => attribute and not a relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is see you are using the singular `question` in your relation definition in the `Exam` model.
That could be the reason why it is null.

Did you also try the plural `questions`, like this:

```
public function questions(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

The rest of the code seems fine, but you could also create the foreign id like this:

```
$table->foreignId('exam_id');
```

You can read more about foreign keys in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)